# I asked if she knew French.(I asked if she knows French)

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

> I asked if she knew French. vs. I asked if she knows French.

If you are a native English speaker, which sentence would you say? Or is there any difference between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I be using 'is' or 'was' in reported speech?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53444/should-i-be-using-is-or-was-in-reported-speech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always say *knew*, and would regard *knows* as a little odd here.

Answer (score 1):

Both can be used. The second one slightly implies that she is someone "present" in your life, but the nuance can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Both the cited examples are syntactically fine, but *usually,* native speakers "backshift" the verb in the complement *(**knew**)* to match the main verb *(**asked**)*.

Whether backshifted or not, the meaning remains the same. It was suggested in [this later question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/333101/if-i-knew-where-she-livedlives-now-id-go-and-see-her) (by a non-native Anglophone TEFL teacher) that if the complement explicitly includes ***now...***

> *If I knew where she lived/lives **now**, I'd go and see her*

...then ***lives*** would have to be *Present* tense. But although I can understand why a non-native speaker might *think* that, [actual native speakers don't](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knew%20where%20he%20lived%20now%2Cknew%20where%20he%20lives%20now&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). It's irrelevant whether or not ***now*** is explicitly included (it's always implicit in such contexts, anyway).